# laravel error exception in formbuilder.php undefined offset:1error

Tags: php, forms, laravel

Am new in php laravel and am getting the following error when displaying a page that should be having a form

> ```
> ErrorException in FormBuilder.php line 525: Undefined offset: 1 (View: E:\mysite\mysite\resources\views\predictions\create.blade.php)
> ```

Here is the form code:

```
 @extends('layouts.master')

 @section('content')
 <h2>Create Predictions</h2>
 {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'predictions.store')) !!}
 <div class="form-group">
 {!! Form::label('title')!!}
 {!! Form::text('title',null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 {!! Form::label('body')!!}
 {!! Form::textarea('body',null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'size'      => '50*3')) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::token() !!}
{!! Form::submit(null, array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Here is the formbuilder code with the exception:

```
protected function setQuickTextAreaSize($options)
{
    $segments = explode('x', $options['size']);

    return array_merge($options, ['cols' => $segments[0], 'rows' =>         

  $segments[1]]);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is no `size` attribute for `textarea` input tag. Remove `'size'      => '50*3'` from below code

```
{!! Form::textarea('body',null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'size'      => '50*3')) !!}
```

Use `rows` and `cols` attribute instead. Since I guess you're trying to set 3 rows and 50 columns as your textarea box size your code may like this:

```
{!! Form::textarea('body',null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'rows'      => '3', 'cols' => '50')) !!}
```